# Higher-order if-then-else in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, higher-order-functions, pointfree

I often have to run my data through a function if the data fulfill certain criteria. Typically, both the function `f` and the criteria checker `pred` are parameterized to the data. For this reason, I find myself wishing for a higher-order `if-then-else` which knows neither `f` nor `pred`.

For example, assume I want to add `10` to all even integers in `(range 5)`. Instead of

```clj
(map #(if (even? %) (+ % 10) %) (range 5))
```

I would prefer to have a helper –let's call it `fork`– and do this:

```clj
(map (fork even? #(+ % 10)) (range 5))
```

I could go ahead and implement `fork` as function. It would look like this:

```clj
(defn fork
  ([pred thenf elsef]
   #(if (pred %) (thenf %) (elsef %)))
  ([pred thenf]
   (fork pred thenf identity)))
```

Can this be done by elegantly combining `core` functions? Some nice chain of `juxt` / `apply` / `some` maybe?

Alternatively, do you know any Clojure library which implements the above (or similar)?

Comment: I can't see much room for improvement for the definition of `fork`. For the two arg arity, you could use `cond->` but this is less clear: `(defn fork [pred thenf] #(cond-> % (pred %) thenf))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alan Thompson mentions, `cond->` is a fairly standard way of implicitly getting the "else" part to be "return the value unchanged" these days. It doesn't really address your hope of being higher-order, though. I have another reason to dislike `cond->`: I think (and argued when `cond->` was being invented) that it's a mistake for it to thread through each matching test, instead of just the first. It makes it impossible to use `cond->` as an analogue to `cond`.

If you agree with me, you might try [`flatland.useful.fn/fix`](https://github.com/clj-commons/useful/blob/master/src/flatland/useful/fn.clj#L30), or one of the other tools in that family, which we wrote years before `cond->`<sup>1</sup>.

`to-fix` is exactly your `fork`, except that it can handle multiple clauses and accepts constants as well as functions (for example, maybe you want to add 10 to other even numbers but replace 0 with 20):

```
(map (to-fix zero? 20, even? #(+ % 10)) xs)
```

It's easy to replicate the behavior of `cond->` using `fix`, but not the other way around, which is why I argue that `fix` was the better design choice.

---

<sup>1</sup> Apparently we're just a couple weeks away from the 10-year anniversary of the final version of `fix`. How time flies.

Comment: [flatland.useful.fn/to-fix](https://github.com/clj-commons/useful/blob/master/src/flatland/useful/fn.clj#L30) indeed does what I am looking for. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it could be very useful to have some kind of higher-order functional construct for this but I am not aware of any such construct. It is true that you could implement a higher order `fork` function, but its usefulness would be quite limited and can easily be achieved using `if` or the `cond->` macro, as suggested in the other answers.

What comes to mind, however, are [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers#_using_transducers). You could fairly easily implement a `forking` transducer that can be composed with other transducers to build powerful and concise sequence processing algorithms.

The implementation could look like this:

```
(defn forking [pred true-transducer false-transducer]
  (fn [step]
    (let [true-step (true-transducer step)
          false-step (false-transducer step)]
      (fn
        ([] (step))
        ([dst x] ((if (pred x) true-step false-step) dst x))
        ([dst] dst))))) ;; flushing not performed.
```

And this is how you would use it in your example:

```
(eduction (forking even?
                   (map #(+ 10 %))
                   identity)

          (range 20))
;; => (10 1 12 3 14 5 16 7 18 9 20 11 22 13 24 15 26 17 28 19)
```

But it can also be [comp](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp)osed with other transducers to build more complex sequence processing algorithms:

```
(into []

      (comp (forking even?
                     (comp (drop 4)
                           (map #(+ 10 %)))
                     (comp (filter #(< 10 %))
                           (map #(vector % % %))
                           cat))
            (partition-all 3))
      
      (range 20))
;; => [[18 20 11] [11 11 22] [13 13 13] [24 15 15] [15 26 17] [17 17 28] [19 19 19]]
```

Comment: Amazing! I have accepted amalloy's answer because it is scoped precisely to the question and points to a library which does exactly what I asked for. Your answer however, expands the mind and gives tremendous food for thought. For this, you have my upvote. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the details, it is often easiest to accomplish this goal using the [cond->](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond-%3E) macro and friends:

```clj
(let [myfn (fn [val] 
             (cond-> val
               (even? val) (+ val 10))) ]
```

with result

```
  (mapv myfn (range 5)) => [10 1 14 3 18]
```

There is a variant [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#literate-threading-macro) that is sometimes helpful:

```
(mapv #(cond-it-> %
         (even? it) (+ it 10))
  (range 5))
```

that allows you to use the special symbol `it` as you thread the value through multiple stages.

---

As the examples show, you have the option to define and name the transformer  function (my favorite), or use the function literal syntax `#(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to define `fork` (with three inputs) could be:

```clj
(defn fork [pred then else]
  (comp
    (partial apply apply)
    (juxt (comp {true then, false else} pred) list)))
```

Notice that in this version the inputs and output can receive zero or more arguments. But let's take a more structured approach, defining some other useful combinators. Let's start by defining `pick` which corresponds to the categorical coproduct (sum) of morphisms:

```clj
(defn pick [actions]
  (fn [[tag val]]
    ((actions tag) val)))

;alternatively
(defn pick [actions]
  (comp
    (partial apply apply)
    (juxt (comp actions first) rest)))
```

E.g. `(mapv (pick [inc dec]) [[0 1] [1 1]])` gives `[2 0]`. Using `pick` we can define `switch` which works like `case`:

```clj
(defn switch [test actions]
  (comp
    (pick actions)
    (juxt test identity)))
```

E.g. `(mapv (switch #(mod % 3) [inc dec -]) [3 4 5])` gives `[4 3 -5]`. Using `switch` we can easily define `fork`:

```clj
(defn fork [pred then else]
  (switch pred {true then, false else}))
```

E.g. `(mapv (fork even? inc dec) [0 1])` gives `[1 0]`. Finally, using `fork` let's also define `fork*` which receives zero or more predicate and action pairs and works like `cond`:

```clj
(defn fork* [& args]
  (->> args
       (partition 2)
       reverse
       (reduce
         (fn [else [pred then]]
           (fork pred then else))
         identity)))

;equivalently
(defn fork* [& args]
  (->> args
       (partition 2)
       (map (partial apply (partial partial fork)))
       (apply comp)
       (#(% identity))))
```

E.g. `(mapv (fork* neg? -, even? inc) [-1 0 1])` gives `[1 1 1]`.